# Intranet project template under visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

Where is the intranet project template under visual studio 2015 ?

**Under visual studio 2015 :**

[image: template project visual studio 2015]

**Under visual studio 2012 :**

[image: template project visual studio 2012]

Comment: It's gone. Why? Were you somehow emotionally attached to it?

Comment: I am just watching some videos tutorials about windows authentication, i guess i need to skip this part when we talk about intranet application.